# Riesz-Dunford-Schwartz functional calculus

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can anyone tell me where to find a good book or lecture note on Riesz-Dunford-Schwartz functional calculus for commuting tuple of operators?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the original article by Taylor:

> *Taylor, Joseph L.*, [**The analytic-functional calculus for several commuting operators**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392329), Acta Math. 125, 1-38 (1970). [ZBL0233.47025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0233.47025).

Is it sufficient for your purposes or are you specifically looking for some more recent exposition of the topic?

Comment: @Igor.Thank you. This will suffice. Sorry for a late reply.